# What should be the Subversion properties for a *.xml file?

Tags: xml, svn, mime-types

What's the correct/best properties to assign to *.xml files in Subversion?

I'm particularly interested in the properties `svn:mime-type` and `svn:needs-lock`.

I think there are two answers, but I'm not sure about which one to choose. The first one is to consider XML files as text files, letting Subversion manage textual merges in them. For this, I would use `svn:mime-type=text/xml` and would **not** use `svn:needs-lock`.

The second would be to consider XML files as binary files, preventing Subversion to perform automatic merges and insisting on lock-before-edit behaviour. For this, I would use `svn:mime-type=application/xml` and would set `svn:needs-lock`.

I think it's ok to treat XML as text if it's the kind of XML file that is edited directly in a text editor, because the user would then be able to resolve any eventual merge conflicts by hand. However, tool generated XML files cannot be easily edited by hand and so should not be automatically merged by Subversion lest the user be put in a situation in which he has to resolve a conflict in an (essentially) binary file.

Being conservative, I'm treatting XML files as binary. But I'm always having to explain this to developers that would rather prefer to be able to edit some XML files directly, with no need to get locks previously.

I would like to know what others think about this and if there really is a danger concerning tools generated XML files or not.

POST CLARIFICATION:

After having read the first three responses I realized that the above question wasn't clear enough.

My doubt is what properties should be configured for `*.xml` files in the `[auto-props]` section of the Subversion configuration file (`~/.subversion/config`)?

The problem is that there can only be one configuration. So, should I be conservative and treat all XML files as binary or should I please the users that edit their XML files by hand and treat all XML files as text by default?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8):

We use both text/xml and application/xml in our Subversion repository. XML that is edited by hand, human readable and thus can be usefully merged we treat as text. This includes things like maven pom files, and build.xml files, docbook files, xhtml documents etc.

```
svn:eol-style=native
svn:mime-type="text/xml; charset=utf-8"  /* so apache sends the right encoding */
```

For XML that's the complex file format for some tool, we treat it as binary. Examples of this are *.fodt (flat ODT), OmniGraffle files, XMI (UML Models) and the like.  A user can not reasonably be epxected to merge such a file, and indeed often the diffs for even trivial changes are large and messy.

```
svn:mime-type="application/xml"
svn:needs-lock="*"
```

Making this distinction has served us well.

Comment: Good point. I've edited my question after having read your answer.

I liked the `charset=utf-8` tip too.

Answer (score 3):

If the XML is generated, you have to ask why it is in Subversion in the first place. I'm with the developers on this one, but an obvious solution if you 
must version control the generated files is to give them extensions other than .xml.

Comment: Good point. As examples of "generated XMLs" that makes sense to be versioned I was thinking of things like FODT, DIA, and XMI files. However, these ones have different extensions and don't pose any problems. I'm afraid, though, that there might be some tools generating XML files with the extension `.xml`.

But I really don't know any...

Answer (score 0):

If the XML is human-readable and well understood, there's no harm treating it like any other text. If it's only machine-readable or not something your developers have a good understanding of, you have to treat it as binary data; your level of understanding and ability to manually manipulate it will be the same.